# Python: convert CSV columns into arrays, except 1st and last row

Tags: python, arrays, csv

I have a CSV file, called results_date.csv which looks like this:

```
Header1 ; Header2 ; Header3
string1=0,1 ; string2=0,2 ; string3=0,3
string4=0,4 ; string5=0,5 ; string6=0,6
..............................
stringX=0,x ; stringY=0,y ; stringZ=0,z
some other big string at the end
```

I want to parse through this file, and save the text into 2 arrays, for columns 1 and 2, but without the equal and the number after it, header and the other big string at the end. Ex:

```
array_for_column1 = ["string1", "string4", ..., "stringX"]
array_for_column2 = ["string2", "string5", ..., "stringY"]
```

These arrays will be used for a confusion matrix.

I tried to do it this way:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import csv

data = csv.reader(open('results_date.csv', 'r'), delimiter=";", quotechar='|')

column1 = []
column2 = []

for row in data:
    column1.append(row[0])
    column2.append(row[1])

print (column1)
print (column2)
```

But it doesn't work. This code only prints the 1st column, and throws an error for the 2nd column.

Thanks for help in advance!

Comment: Presumably the last row in your file does not contain a `';'`. In your loop you could check if `len(row) >= 2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the last row does not contain a `;`. You can do the following:

```
with open('results_date.csv', 'r') as f:
    data = csv.reader(f, delimiter=";", quotechar='|')
    next(data)  # skip headers

    # transpose rows to columns while safe-checking row length
    columns = list(zip(*(row for row in data if len(row) >= 2)))[:2]

    # process cells: strip, split on '=', take first part
    column1, column2 = [[s.strip().split('=')[0] for s in c] for c in columns]
```

Comment: Works as a charm! Thank you very much!